# Generate table for mapping IPAddress as INET type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate

I got a mapping that maps `IPAddress` object field to database.

There is `inet` type in PostgreSQL suited for this, but in my case it uses `bytea` type instead when it generates schema.

Is there a way to force resulting generated schema type for this column to be `inet` actually in DB?

I also happen to have this requirement on composite ID (whicg is required)

```
CompositeId()
.KeyProperty(x => x.Date, "for_date")
.KeyProperty(x => x.Address, var => var.ColumnName("ipaddress"));
```

You cant really use CustomSqlType on key property part.

I also tried using

```
public class IPAddressPropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Property.PropertyType == typeof(IPAddress))
            instance.CustomSqlType("inet");
    }
}
```

But I get exception about invalid property convention

Comment: Let's see if I understand the question. You want to generate a database schema using `nhibernate`, and when you try to write the code to do that in `fluent`, it generates a column of type `bytea`. You'd rather it generate a column of type `inet`. Is that right?

Comment: @Catcall yes, precisely this.

Answer (score 4):

```
Map(x => x.IPAddress)
    .CustomSqlType("inet")
    .CustomType<IPAddressToInetUserType>();  // maybe needed, you should check
```

Comment: Is it a working solution or a supposedly working? Because it doesn't work for me I think.

Comment: this is the way to go when mapping custom types. it is working for for many other types hence it most probably works here too. **note: since it is a key property you need IIdConvention**

Comment: there is a similar case for hibernate https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=984186

Comment: read that thread, although its like 2 years old so thought maybe theres some progress in the area.